# Automatic suggestion of using another network on Stack Exchange, especially server fault or Security

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I found myself going to stack overflow to ask a question. It seemed to have not been asked before, but like a good user, I googled my question after typing it out. Instant result for my exact question on security (It was the right place, after all).

I feel as though I see a lot of questions pop up that get down voted and closed/moved for being on the wrong network, which is fine, but a lot of people don't know those other two networks (Security and Server Fault) even exist, as well as several others that I can't come up with, which helps my point.

Perhaps even just looking at keywords like "authorized" or "linux" or "cron", I don't know, but something. I think it would help a lot of newer users and non-power users like myself.

Comment: If we redirect anything that matches *"authorized" or "linux" or "cron"* to either SF or Security, expect the fine folks there to start throwing rocks at us in the street (and with good reason). We would need much finer control about what goes where, in other words -- human intervention, as we do now.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't think it should redirect automatically, just detect and suggest. If I had something that said "Looks like you're trying to ask a security question on Stack Overflow"

Comment: I would support this if it left the normal search alone, then just expanded the dupe-suggester-box to the rest of the technology Stack Exchange sites. It should search using the normal dupe-suggester-box algorithm but just expand its search radius.

Comment: @TinyGiant So you think it should always check the other sites using the same algorithm, not based on keywords? I'm open to that, but I feel like it might start to make certain topics, like a lot of nodejs or python (hot topics over at Security) more confusing to search. I may be under-estimating the search algorithm, though. It does tend to find things I couldn't on my own, within the same network.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not talking about question migration, but about returning results from other sites in response to search queries, then there are no problems with "don't migrate crap" and actually a pretty good chance of a user learning that their topic is covered by a different site.

I'd be in favor of that, or even just generating search links for sister sites based on the words in the query.

Comment: This is the main point of my suggestion, yes.

Comment: Though iff that's done, there must be an obvious and easy way to restrict to the local site too.